# Dataset with Multiple Choice Questions for fine tuning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, data, gpt

I hope it's allowed to ask here, but I am looking for a dataset (the format is not that important) that is similar to SQuAD, but it also contains false answers to the questions. I wanna use it to fine tune GPT-3, and all I find is either MC questions based on a text, but with no distractors, or classical quizzes that have no context before each question.

I have a code that generates distractors, and I can just plug it in there, but I was wondering if there was any pre-made dataset.

Comment: Just a quick heads up. GPT-3 (6.6B parameters) is not open source and there is a cost attached to using the API. Fine tuning can be expensive too. An alternative is to use GPT-J which is open source. I myself have fine tuned GPT-J(6B parameters) to generate Scenario based MCQ's. Let me know if you need help!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the RACE datasets. It's an english reading comprehension multiple-choice question & answer dataset from exams conducted in China.

Answer (score -1):

This is also feasible dataset for you: named swag
"https://huggingface.co/datasets/swag?row=9"